# Watch both Chaplin files and express node.js files with brunch

Tags: express, brunch, chaplinjs

I am working on a Express node.js server and Chaplin client web app using Brunch.

I want brunch to recompile and restart my express server if any server side code changes **and** recompile my Chaplin client if any client side code changes.

Brunch already watches my Chaplin code but I cannot get it to restart the express server.

I have added the server directory to the path in the config.coffee but this only recompiles the client side code and doesn't restart the server.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) - pretty much no configuration necessary to get started, just npm install and then start your server as argument via nodemon.

Install using npm

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

then start your server using

```
nodemon server.js
```

You'll probably want to exclude your chaplin code, otherwise you may find it restarts unnecessarily.